# How to compare two or more mean AUC

Tags: machine-learning, p-value, auc

I have different machine learning models  and for each of them after a 10-fold cross validation I obtained a mean AUC (+-std). Now, How can I check if there is a statistically significant difference (p-value) among the mean AUC?

Comment: I wouldn't do this. Anyway, can you post some sample data?

Comment: Example of AUC for three models: 0.66 (±0.04) 0.74 (±0.04) 0.77 (±0.04)

Comment: Do you only have these statistics or can you also obtain the raw 10 values for each fold?

Comment: Unfortunately I saved only the mean value. I could get the individual measurements on each test set but I have to re-calculate them for each model.

Answer (score 1):

Don't.

A hypothesis test aims to test an hypothesis, or rather the null hypothesis (this is beside the point here). But you **know** that your models are different because, as you write, you have different machine-learning models.

I guess what you want to know is something like whether approach A is consistently, or on average, better than B. That is what the numbers (mean and se) tell you. More importantly, they also tell you *how much* better A is than B. You don't get any further information from knowing the hypothesis-test results.

Side note: As AUC approaches 1, estimates become non-normally distributed, making the sem less useful than the confidence interval. Also, sensitivity to differences decreases as AUC approaches 1, and I have seen people compare $e^\text{AUC}$ rather than AUC itself in this situation.

Comment: I have to confront different models considering a metric (AUC or sensitivity etc) on the same data, but also on different data. I should use a hypothesis test to determine if my models are significantly different from one another. An AUC of 0.8 is significantly different from 0.75 ? To assess whether the difference in AUC between highest performing classifier
and the other methods was statistically significant, someone uses the Wilcoxon signed-rank test. Other DeLong method. I am really confusing.